# Full screen plugin doesnt hide status bar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, google-eclipse-plugin

I have a Kepler (4.3?) version of Eclipse and I tried several versions of fullscreen plugins. They all hide menu bar and windows 7 ribbon, but neither hides status bar (where it shows cursor position i.e. 75:14)

```
I have an old ThinkPad 1280x800 and I need that vertical space desperately.

I have tried:
>"gr.scharf.fullscreen"
>"org.ugosan.eclipse.fullscreen_1.0.8"
>"cn.pande.eclipsex.fullscreen_1.0.7"

They all fail to hide status bar. Help! Do I need older/other version of Eclipse?

Thanks,
Ignas
```